# AlarmManager getRepeating possible

Tags: android, gps, alarmmanager

I am using a AlarmManager for check GPS location every x minutes:

```
private void updateLocationTimer(int interval) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_REQUEST_LOCATION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (interval > 0) 
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pendingIntent);
    else    
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

1. This method is called after changing GPS interval in Preferences.
2. And it is called on reboot with the help of an AutoStartReceiver.
3. And it is called on every start of my App.

The problem is that 3. overrides and restarts the alarm on every App start, even the interval is 12 hours.

Is there a method like AlarmManager.getRepeating available to check the last alarm?

Or can I rely on the AlarmManager once the interval is set with (1.) or (2.)?
What happens if my App crashes? Is there a situation where Android will cancel my alarm automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method like AlarmManager.getRepeating available to check the last alarm?

No, sorry. `AlarmManager` is a write-only API.

> Or can I rely on the AlarmManager once the interval is set with (1.) or (2.)? What happens if my App crashes? Is there a situation where Android will cancel my alarm automatically?

A simple crash should not cause a problem. If the user force-stops you (via the "Force Stop" button in Settings), that will also unschedule your alarms, among other effects.

The approach that I recommend is just tracking when you last got control via the alarm, in every invocation of `LocationService`, such as via a value in `SharedPreferences`. Then, your launcher icon can have logic like this:

- If the value does not exist, then this is presumably the first run of your app after installation, so schedule the alarm and update the `SharedPreferences` to reflect that you got control here
- If the value exists, and it is plausible (e.g., you are trying to get control every 12 hours, and you last got control 7 hours ago), you assume everything is fine and do nothing
- If the value exists, and it is implausible (e.g., you are trying to get control every 12 hours, and you last got control 3 weeks ago), you assume that the user force-stopped you, so you set up your alarms again and update the `SharedPreferences` as well

Some other notes for your specific case:

- You cannot use a service directly with a `_WAKEUP` alarm. Use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` in conjunction with your service, to ensure the device stays awake. And, it may be that you will wind up doing your own `WAKE_LOCK` stuff instead (though still using a `BroadcastReceiver` as the thing that is started via the alarm), as `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` was written with `IntentService` in mind, and you won't be using that.
- You may be better served just using the `PendingIntent` flavors of the location-updates APIs on `LocationManager` or `GoogleApiClient`, rather than maintaining your own service for all of this.